# Unicode printing on a PRINTER in VB6

Tags: unicode, printing, vb6, cjk

I'm trying to print a Unicode (Chinese) string on a printer (well, actually PDFCreator) but all I get is a VERTICAL print of the characters.

I use the `TextOutW` function imported from `gdi32.dll`:

```
TextOutW dest.hDC, x, y, StrConv(szText, vbUnicode), Len(szText)
```

And if I try to print "0.12" (if I print Chinese characters, I get the same result anyway), I get

```
0
.
1
2
```

If I use the `dest.Print` function, I am not able to print Unicode.

Anyway, `TextOutW` works WONDERFULLY on the screen.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

What is the definition of `szText`? Is it a VB6 string? In which case try

```
Private Declare Function  Lib "gdi32" Alias "TextOutW" ( _
  ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, _
  ByVal lpStringU As Long, ByVal nCount As Long) As Long  

TextOutW dest.hDC, x, y, StrPtr(szText), Len(szText)
```

Note

- `StrPtr` not `StrConv(... , vbUnicode)`
- `Declare` for `TextOutW` has `ByVal lpStringU As Long`

Comment: Yes, it is a vb6 string
It does not work. the result is a series of squares and unreadable characters. exactly as I want to print a ANSI string with UNICODE functions.

Comment: How did you get an ANSI string into `szText`?? VB6 strings usually contain Unicode data. And can you please post the `Declare` for `TextOutW`?  (Also see my edits to the answer.)

Comment: I think you might be sending a Unicode string to `StrConv`, which invokes ANSI->Unicode conversion. This will produce lots of Unicode null characters in your string. Then the VB6 runtime might be implicitly converting Unicode back to ANSI (if your `Declare` is `ByVal lpsz As String`). This could produce a Unicode string, but with lots of null Unicode characters. Then you might have a different text alignment behaviour on your "printer" than on your screen, so the null Unicode characters might have a different effect on the "printer"

Comment: Using the "Long" type for the lpStringU is crucial as well. The ASCII equivalent API declaration uses a string.

Comment: @WarrenRox Yes, absolutely. That's *the* crucial thing.