# Vb6 Printer Object Print Japanese

Tags: object, printing, vb6

I want to use printer (windows driver) to print Japanese in a vb 6 project.

My project is in Japanese Windows Environment (the OS is English Originally, set Japan region and related language).

I use **Printer object** to print a simple string type of Japanese such as "レジースター", the code  like

```
  Dim s As String
  s="レジースター"
  Printer.Print s
  Printer.EndDoc
```

but the output result is a set of messy code like "OEvƒOEƒ|[ƒg"

Does anybody who can succeeded in printing out Japanese with **Vb6 Printer Object** in **Japanese language Windows Envrionment**, please help me.

Finally find the key is simple, it's a little bit tricky but I still don't know why. Just set the font of the Printer Object like "Printer.Font.Charset = 128" (128 for Japanese)

ATTN: Pls pay attention to my case, my OS is English with the language and region setting to Japanese.

What make me confused is that the default ANSI of Windows. As we know, the default value of Printer.Font.Charset is 0, it means ANSI (IF the language environment is Japanese then it will use code page 932, if it is English, it will use Windows-1252).

My OS is Japanese (set to Japanese, not purely, Originally English OS), when I try to Write a file in Japanese it can display Japanese, but when I use the Printer Object to Print, it does have 0(ANSI) value of .Font.Charset, but actually it still use the original OS code page, so it is wired. And when I try to set the system to Chinese and Korean, both of the language is normal, only Japanese have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

the trick that i have used for something like this is to use double StrConv() functions, one with the vbFromUnicode constant and the other with the vbToUnicode constant.

It takes alittle experimenting to get right , but it should look something like this, swap the constants and/or codepage values until you get the right conversion for your system

```
Dim s as string
s="レジースター"
Dim newS as string
newS = StrConv((StrConv(s,FromUnicode,CodePage1),ToUnicode,CodePage2)
Printer.Print newS
```

CodePage*N* is the Windows codepage value, 1252 for English, 932 for Japanese

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried the StrConv method. It works when my system is not Japanese, I finally find the answer with the help of my college.

Answer (score 0):

Despite all strings in VB6 are Unicode (UTF-16), when it comes to interfacing with the world VB6 is completely non-Unicode.

You cannot store `レジースター` in your project file because the file is in ANSI.
You cannot simply pass a string to a declared API function because it will undergo an automatic conversion to ANSI first. To avoid this, you have to declare string parameters as pointers.

Apparently same happens to the `Print` call - the string gets converted to the currect ANSI codepage before it reaches the printer driver.

You can try printing manually by [creating a device context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183490.aspx) and [printing on it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13515686/11683).

Or you can [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=vb6+printer+unicode) for another solution, like [this one](http://www.unisuite.com/product014.htm) (I did not try it).

Comment: Thank you for reply first, but I can store my project with Japanese.      I don't know whether it is because of my Japanese Windows environment.    In fact, the Japanese stored in a resource file, and I load the resource file and print them. I can print Chinese in Chinese environment, but cannot print Japanese in Japanese Environment. I know it may be the codepage problem, but I tried convert Japanese to Unicode, but it still not work...

Comment: The term "ANSI" is used in a confusing way in Windows development. It means the current code page on Windows. If the Windows setting "language for non-Unicode programs" is set to Japanese, then the current code page will be Japanese, and Japanese text should work. The strings will be converted to the Japanese code page before being sent to the printer, written to files, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I have seen some documents about Vb6 Encoding. I knew vb6 would convert unicode to current ANSI automatically. I tried both "Write Japanese Strings to a File" and "Print Out". I could display the Japanese in a txt file (when Write into it), so it should be my current Japanese Windows Codepage:932 (Japanese Shift-JIS), (PS: my OS is English setting Japanese Environment) but when I try to use the Printer Object to Print, it seemed to encoded by Windows 1252 (My English OS default code page). I have set the right font, and I am confused about it.