# display "≤" character into a VB6 Label

Tags: vb6, special-characters

I am trying to set  `≤` character into a **VB6** `Label`.

Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

The code would be 2264 .

`Label.Text = Chr(2264)` generates an error
`Label.Text = ChrW$(2264)` sets a question mark "?"

Does anyone know how to get this `≤` character

Comment: VB6 supports Unicode in the sense that the strings are Unicode. Its forms are non-Unicode though and are controlled by the character set for non-Unicode programs (apparently I [have already said all that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6552368/11683)). If the character you want is not part of the currently selected character set for non-Unicode programs, VB6 will not display it on the form unless you owner-draw everything with API calls that support Unicode (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13515686/11683).

Comment: as a workaround, you can use &< in your caption. this will display something very similar to your desired result

Comment: VB6 Forms are not the problem, you just have to use Unicode-aware controls on them.  VB6 doesn't have a Unicode Label control, but there are plenty floating around out there as OCXs and as .CTL UserControl modules you can compile into programs.

Comment: I ll use the  nabuchodonossor's solution with &< that nearly displays as ≤.
Thx alll!

Answer (score 1):

```
Label.Text = ChrW(&H2264) ' <-- &H for Hexadecimal
```

`2264` is the *Hexadecimal* code, you can see it [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf).

In Decimal, it is `ChrW(8804)`.

Comment: Thx for the explanation.
However, both ChrW(&H2264) and ChrW(8804) are displayed as "=" into the Label :(

Comment: I undrstand that, it worked for me in (Excel) VBA actually.  For Vb6 apps to work with Unicode you should follow @GSerg 's comment.

Answer (score 0):

The stock `Symbol` font contains that symbol at an ansi codepoint and so works without requiring unicode awareness, as a contrived example with 3 autosizing labels:

```
lbl_left.Caption = "999"

lbl_middle.Font.Name = "Symbol"
lbl_middle.Caption = ChrW$(&HA3)
lbl_middle.Left = lbl_left.Left + lbl_left.Width + Me.TextWidth(" ")

lbl_right.Caption = "1000"
lbl_right.Left = lbl_middle.Left + lbl_middle.Width + Me.TextWidth(" ")
```

Comment: Works when the "Language for non-Unicode programs" is e.g. `en-gb`. Displays `?` when "Language for non-Unicode programs" is e.g. `ru-ru`.